# Show X-Axis Gaps -- Highstocks

Tags: highcharts

I am having an issue with getting my data to show a lapse in data being sent on the X-axis. What should be seen as a gap in the line is just being merged into the same line, for example in this img the data goes from 4am to 9am due to internet being out yet there is no lapse in the line. [image]

This is the code for the example that I have at the moment.

```
$.getJSON('mkjson.php?device=<?echo $device_name;?>&sensor=<?echo $sensor_name;?>&pin=<?echo $pin;?>&user=<?echo $_SESSION['user'];?>', function(data) {
    // Create the chart
    window.chart = new Highcharts.StockChart({
    credits : {
            enabled : false
        },
        chart : {
            renderTo : 'container',
            zoomType: 'x'
        },

        rangeSelector : {
            selected : 1
        },

        title : {

            text : 'Device:<?echo $device_name;?>'
        },
        subtitle : {
            text : 'Sensor:<?echo $sensor_name;?>'

        },

        xAxis: {
        type: 'datetime',
        dateTimeLabelFormats: {
            second: '%m-%d<br/>%l:%M:%S%p',
            minute: '%m-%d<br/>%l:%M%p',
            hour: '%m-%d<br/>%l:%M%p',
            day: '%m-%d',
            week: '%m-%d',
            month: '%Y-%m',
            year: '%Y'
        }
    },

        yAxis : {
            min: <?echo $yaxis_min;?>,
            max: <?echo $yaxis_max;?>,
            title : {               
                text : '<?echo $unit?>'
            },
            <?if(isset($alert1) ||isset ($alert2)){?>
            plotLines: [{
                color: '#FF0000',
                width: 1,
                value: <?echo $alert1;?>
            }, {
                color: '#FF0000',
                width: 1,
                value: <?echo $alert2;?>
            }]
            <?}?>

        },

        rangeSelector : {
            buttons : [{
                type : 'minute',
                count : 10,
                text : '10m'
            }, {
                type : 'hour',
                count : 1,
                text : '1H'
            }, 
            {
                type : 'day',
                count : 1,
                text : '1D'
            },
            {
                type : 'day',
                count : 3,
                text : '3D'
            }],
            selected : 3,
            inputEnabled : false
        },          

        series : [{
            name : '<?echo $unit;?>',
            data : data,
            tooltip: {
            valueDecimals: 2,
        formatter: function() {
            return Highcharts.numberFormat(this.y, 2);
        }},
            dataGrouping: {
            enabled: true
            }
        }]
    });
});
```

Also this is the example from highstocks in jsfiddle that I am trying to use to see how they were able to accomplish it.

http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/stock/demo/data-grouping/

Answer (score 2):

To add gaps in Highcharts you have to specify when lapse ends. To do that you have to use `null` as data point, for example:

```
series: [{
    data: [{ 
        x: Date.UTC(2012,1,1,4,0,0,0),
        y: 24
    },{ 
        x: Date.UTC(2012,1,1,4,0,0,1), //to create a gap
        y: null
    },{ 
        x: Date.UTC(2012,1,1,9,0,0,0), //new data comes
        y: 24
    }]
}]
```

Comment: So this is not able to be done dynamically by pulling data from sql?

Comment: I'm not sure what is wrong in my example to be pulled from database. The problem is that how Highcharts should know that there should be a gap? If you know when gap should appear, add that gap manually.

Comment: I think what the OP is asking is whether or not Highcharts can automatically detect gaps along the x axis.  I personally don't see why not.  If the interval is set to one day, for example, and 2 days are missing in the series, why can't it automatically fill in those days and set the y axis value to null or zero for those gaps.  If it can't do it automatically, then it means we need to do a lot of server-side work to fill in the gaps ourselves.  I'm personally having trouble with that part.  Can anyone provide tips for how to fill in the gaps on either the server or the client?

Comment: If you set `pointInterval` then each of your points will get specific timestamp according to index in array. If you are missing some of points, put there nulls. Let's say I have hours: 10:32, 14:11, 14:35 - irregular hours, so what gaps (and where) should be applied? Note, Highstock has support for `gapSize` - maybe that's what you need?

Answer (score 1):

[plotOptions.series.gapSize](http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#plotOptions.series.gapSize) is the correct answer.

> Defines when to display a gap in the graph. A gap size of 5 means that
>   if the distance between two points is greater than five times that of
>   the two closest points, the graph will be broken

For hourly time series I use 6. When the data stops for over 6 hours.

```
 plotOptions: {
  series: {
    gapSize: 6,
    . . .
```

Answer (score 0):

If you switch to a column graph (or maybe a scatter chart), you'll see the individual data points better, and Highstock won't connect them with lines.  Paweł stated, Highstock doesn't know that any data is missing -- it's designed to smoothly connect the time series data you provide to it.